# How to get upperbound of wildcarded generic field?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, wildcard

I have a field like `List<? extends MyPojo> myPojos = new ArrayList<>();`.

I want to -through reflection- get the fact that the upper bound of `myPojos` is of type `MyPojo`.

I can get the [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) no problem, and then [`getGenericType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType%28%29), but that just returns a [`Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) which has no methods on it. I can cast it to [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html), but [`getActualTypeArguments()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29).

The `toString()` method on the `ParameterizedType` returns the expected value, there seems to be no way to access the information on the wildcard upper boud, and all the implementations of `ParameterizedType` seem to be in `sun.` packages.

So, can I -without parsing the `toString()` output- get the upperbound of the generic type without resorting to depending on `sun.*` classes? Or is this information lost due to erasure?

Comment: Why? It's right there in the source code.

Comment: @EJP I'm doing code generation using reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need to cast to `ParameterizedType`, and then cast the `Type` values from `getActualTypeArguments()` to `WildcardType`, which has a `getUpperBounds()` method.

So

```
assert MyPojo.class == ((WildcardType) ((ParameterizedType) listField.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).getUpperBounds()[0];
```

Comment: Editted with a code sample. AFAICT you can't do this safely without `instanceof` otherwise you are casting blindly.